# 'Back' button to previous Modal Popup (Ajax Modal Popup Extender)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have a button on my Default.aspx which launches a 'Terms and Condtions' modal pop up window (popup1). I then have a button on the modal popup which launches another modal popup (popup2) over the top (page 2 of my terms and conditions).

I want to add a back button to modalpopup2 which closes popup2 and shows modalpopup1 so the user has the 'forward/back' option from popup2.

I've added 'ButtonBack' and tried...

```
protected void ButtonBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Popup1.Show();
}
```

But this just redirects back to my default.aspx. Any ideas on how to get around this with C# or maybe some javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help!

Here's my final script...

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function fn_Next(sender, args) {
        $find('ModalTerms1').hide();
        $find('ModalTerms2').show();
    }

    function fn_Back(sender, args) {
        $find('ModalTerms2').hide();
        $find('ModalTerms1').show();
```

}

```
    function fn_Last(sender, args) {
        $find('ModalTerms3').hide();
        $find('ModalTerms1').hide();
        $find('ModalTerms2').show();
    } 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function fn_Next() {
            $find(ModalPopupExtender1).hide();
            $find(ModalPopupExtender2).show();
        }

        function fn_Next1() {
            $find(ModalPopupExtender2).hide();
            $find(ModalPopupExtender3).show();
        }

        function fn_Back() {
            $find(ModalPopupExtender2).hide();
            $find(ModalPopupExtender1).show();
        }

        function fn_Back1() {
            $find(ModalPopupExtender3).hide();
            $find(ModalPopupExtender2).show();
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">    

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var ModalPopupExtender1 = '<%= ModalPopupExtender1.ClientID %>';
        var ModalPopupExtender2 = '<%= ModalPopupExtender2.ClientID %>';
        var ModalPopupExtender3 = '<%= ModalPopupExtender3.ClientID %>';
    </script>

    <asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" Text="Show Popup" runat="server" />
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup"
        PopupControlID="panelPopup1" BackgroundCssClass="bkgPopup" OkControlID="btnNext" OnOkScript="fn_Next()">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="panelPopup2"
        PopupControlID="panelPopup2" BackgroundCssClass="bkgPopup" OkControlID="btnBack" OnOkScript="fn_Back()"
            CancelControlID="btnNext1" OnCancelScript="fn_Next1()">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender3" runat="server" TargetControlID="panelPopup3"
        PopupControlID="panelPopup3" BackgroundCssClass="bkgPopup" OkControlID="btnBack1" OnOkScript="fn_Back1()">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

    <asp:Panel ID="panelPopup1" runat="server" CssClass="panelPopup">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Popup 1</td>
                </tr>
            </table>            
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next" />
        </div>        
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="panelPopup2" runat="server" CssClass="panelPopup">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Popup 2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>            
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" Text="Back" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnNext1" runat="server" Text="Next" />
        </div>        
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="panelPopup3" runat="server" CssClass="panelPopup">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Popup 3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>            
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnBack1" runat="server" Text="Back" />
        </div>        
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Great, thanks. This runs but on firing my back button it removes the modal background but not the popup window. The content in my modal popups are held in tables. Prehaps this could prevent the javascript from closing the popup window?

Comment: Ok, I have 3 Modal popups. This is my script. I can navigate between 1, 2 and 3. Back to 2 from 3 but not back to 1??!                                                                                                                                    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function fn_Next(sender, args) {

$find(Modal).hide();

$find(Modal2).show();
}
function fn_Back(sender, args) {

$find(Modal2).hide();

$find(Modal).show();
}
function fn_Last(sender, args) {

$find(Modal3).hide();

$find(Modal1).hide();

$find(Modal2).show();
} 
</script>

Comment: When you calling fn_Last() no need to hide already hidden window - just hide current window.